# How to iterate two arrays in parallel of different sizes in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

in my code having two arrays of different size which coming from different MySQL queries

i want to iterate these arrays parallel

like

```
foreach($qrs as $qrow){
foreach($d as $q){
         echo rtrim($q);
         echo $qrow['answer_cnt'];
           }
 }
```

but it will not get different values of $q?

Comment: if both arrays are similar in count and structure, you could use a `for` instead or use a `MultipleIterator`

Comment: no size of array will different

Comment: How both the array looks and you is the desired output?

Comment: [MultipleIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) can handle arrays of different sizes when instantiated with the `MIT_NEED_ANY` flag

Answer (score 0):

it should work as long as the logic is correct. no matter whichever array is less in count than the other array in the outer or the inner array. since, both array indexes has no interaction with each other, it will work. in cases such as ;

```
echo $qrowp[$q->some_index] or echo $q[$qrow->some_index]
```

may give you error in some cases